# How could I calculate the exact amount of force I need to apply to a mass to get it to orbit around another mass?

Tags: gravity, orbital-motion, planets

I am currently taking AP Physics, and we are learning about gravitational forces in planets. We know the equation for gravity:

$$F_g=\frac {Gm_1 m_2} {r^2}$$

But, with this equation alongside the relevant equations in mind, how would one go about finding how much force to apply to a planet, given all the needed properties?

Comment: Your equation cannot be correct. Equating square of velocity to square-root of force doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your question is very unclear in other ways. What do you want to accomplish by apply this force? Are you looking for how much force you need to keep an orbiting planet in a circular orbit? To get from some non-orbiting situation to orbit? Something else? Not clear.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Yeah, I realized after posting this question that I had the equation _very_ incorrect, so I'll fix it for more sensibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an object of mass $m$ to maintain a circular orbit you need an inward force $F_\mathrm{inward}=\frac{mv^2}{r}$. This force is now gravity $F_\mathrm{inward}=F_\mathrm{gravity}=G\frac{mM}{r^2}$. Sovling for $v$, you obtain $$ v=\sqrt{\frac{MG}{r}}$$.

It is worth noting that this result is independent on the mass $m$ of the orbiting object. Now, time for your question: how can you reach this velocity $v$? The physical property that you want is *momentum* $p=mv$. Momentum is what you gain, when a force $F$ is acting on you in a time $\Delta t$:  $$\Delta p =m\Delta v =F \Delta t$$.

So if you start from $v=0$, you need to apply the force $F=\frac{mv}{\Delta t}$ over the time $\Delta t$.

Comment: And this force is in the direction from $m_1$ to $m_2$?

Comment: Yes. And also from $m_2$ to $m_1$. According to Newtons third law, there is always en equal an opposite force. For example, the force on an orbiting satellite from the earth is equal to the force on the earth from the orbiting satellite.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: NO, this force must be applied perpendicular to the line joining both masses, otherwise they will collide. Plus v in the first equation is tangential velocity!

Comment: Based on the previous comment, I edited my answer slightly by naming the inward force $F_\mathrm{inward}$ and the gravity force $F_\mathrm{gravity}$. The last force $F$ used to gain momentum should be applied as @Wolphramjonny describes.

Answer (score 0):

Force doesn't matter (or if it does, it matters indirectly). Energy does, but not force.

For example, suppose you're trying to get a spacecraft into orbit, and you calculate the velocity needed is $10 km/s$. How do you accelerate an object to $10 km/s$? You could apply a lot of force (by $F = ma$, this is equivalent to high acceleration) for a brief time, and you'll get there. Alternatively you could apply a small amount of force for a long time, and you'll also get there.

If you wanted to know how to get there *within a certain time*, then force begins to matter, because you'll have a minimum acceleration that you need (which you can solve for via the kinematic equation $v = u + at$). Once you have the minimum acceleration, you can compute the minimum force necessary to get that acceleration.